# SQLite transaction behaviour using greendao

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, transactions, greendao

I am using greendao as ORM library in my Android project and have problems understanding the behaviour of transactions.

greendao offers an API `runInTx(Runnable r)` .
My question is, how will two calls of this method from different Threads will be handled?

Thread 1

```
public void thread1() {
    DaoManager.INSTANCE.getDaoSession().runInTx(new Runnable()
    {
        doQueries();
        doInsertsAndUpdates();
    }
}
```

Thread 2

```
public void thread2() {
      DaoManager.INSTANCE.getDaoSession().runInTx(new Runnable()
    {
        doQueries();
        doInsertsAndUpdates();
    }
}
```

I have seen, that `runInTx` is calling `SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction` in exclusive mode, so no other thread can read/write to database while this transaction is open.
But what i cannot figure out is, when thread1 is doing his job (i.e. `doQueries`) will the other thread (i.e thread2) blocked, so **`doQueries` and `doInsertsAndUpdates` of thread2 will not be performed** until thread1 has finished the transaction?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction` is a blocking call.